# RTE Inserting/Rendering Link Appending Text

Tags: media-library, links, richtext-editor

I am looking for the best way to append to the text of a RTE media link (PDF file type). Either on the insert or when the link is being rendered. I looked at the MediaProvider and I noticed that only returns the link and not the html with the text. I also looked at Rich Text Commands.js file and found that is where the final link is being generated. So possibly I can append on insert if that is the correct place. Ideally though I would like to do it when the link is rendered. Has anyone done something similar?

Here is the code that I want to accomplish. You will see the font awesome markup is write before the link text.

```
<a href="-/media/E4CE71E2A24C4ACAA6B9AE21E9F1DA64.ashx"><span class="pdflink"><em class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></em></span>PDF Text Title</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sitecore way to replace the text in a Rich Text field would be to create a custom processor in `<renderField>` pipeline, insert it before `RenderWebEditing` to ensure all links in fields are expanded. You would then need to wrap the text of the all `<a>` elements which links to a pdf with the additonal markup you require, probably best done using something like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) which is available in a default install of Sitecore. The process is very similar to this blog post by John West about [adding Title attributes to images in Rich Text fields](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/apply-image-titles-to-rich-text-fields-with-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms). You can see the code in the [Github repo](https://github.com/jammykam/Sitecore.SharedSource.JohnWest/blob/master/src/AddImageTitles/AddImageTitles.cs).

If you are using Glass Mapper then you will additionally to use the `ForceRenderField` setting to force the field to run through the `RenderField` pipeline or create a custom [Data Mapper](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial19) since Glass does not use the pipeline in Normal or Preview mode.

But, it looks like you are trying to show an icon using [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons) on all links to pdf files. I suggest that this is much more easily achieved using CSS, the [endswith attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and [::before selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) with content to set the icon.

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div>
  <p>this is some sample text</p>
  <p><a href="/-/media/document.pdf">this is a document link</a></p>
  <p><a href="/some/page">this is a regular link</a></p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```html
a[href$=".pdf"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 0.25em;
}

a[href$=".pdf"]:before {
    content: "\f1c1";
    font-family: FontAwesome;    
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.5em;
 }
```

**Output:**

[image: Sample output]

You can see a [Codepen demo here](https://codepen.io/jammykam/pen/oprOgm).

You can find the unicode character code for each icon one the FontAwesome site, for example for [`file-pdf-o`](http://fontawesome.io/icon/file-pdf-o/):

[image: Fontawesome unicode]

Comment: Thanks I like the CSS approach. In order for that to work I believe I would have to replace the ashx extension to pdf. I was hoping there was an easy way to append to text when the media file is a PDF. Easy to do when I render a media link, but not so easy when it gets rendered from an RTE.

Comment: However I might be able to add the class to the RTE. Then the content editor can select it.

Comment: Yes, it would require you to replace the ashx extension with pdf, or more correctly, set config setting `Media.RequestExtension=""`. This has been the default for latest few releases and has been recommended practice for a long time. If you have this set, then remember, the .ashx will get correctly expanded in normal and preview mode to a proper URL with extension.

Comment: One slight change I did. The css approached work, but since the url had a query string I had to do "a[href*=".pdf"]:before {" instead. Replaced the $ with * basically. Thanks again for your help.